# Javascript span with content, set text(), revert back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span with a DIV like the following:

```
<span class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
   Here is my <?php echo $DIV-CONTENT; ?>
  </div>
</span>
```

Now I set can set my content to the span with something like:

```
 $(.span.foo).text("This removed my innerDiv");
```

Now I have this working in some longer piece of code that does exactly the same as above but I'm unable to unset this text in some way and .show() or whatever() my < div> back.

I would assume this is possible but unsetting, removing, adding the attribute but not what I can get working.

I'm actually unsure if it's possible as you really need to "reset" the page for this ?

Comment: Store the original value to a variable (use something like `var oldDiv = $('.span.foo div').html();`), then use `$('.span.foo').html(oldDiv);` to set it back if needed. Exactly where you store and how you restore is based on your use case, but should be fairly obvious to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div>` isn't hidden, it is completely discarded. You're **overwriting** it. If you want to retain the `<div>` and put it back in the content, you need to actually store it aside in a variable, so you can manually restore it later.

```js
// Store a handle to the div so we can restore it later
var div = $('span.foo div');

$('#clear').click(function () {
  $('span.foo').text("This removed my innerDiv");
});

$('#restore').click(function () {
  $('span.foo').html(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
   Here is my <?php echo $DIV-CONTENT; ?>
  </div>
</span>

<a href="#" id="clear">clear it</a>

<a href="#" id="restore">restore it</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? Won't your `div` variable reference a jquery object that starts out holding a reference to the div but then after setting the text of the span that reference will be invalid because the div is  *gone*. You'd need to make a copy, or manually detach the div before setting the span's text.

Comment: @nnnnnn What do you mean "gone"? It's not "gone", as I still have a reference to it.

Comment: Well that is what I wanted to confirm. So holding a reference to it means it isn't gone even though its parent's text gets set?

Comment: OK, this is what I thought indeed. Would this work with full html and dropdowns, etc in it ? I think it should.

Comment: Thanks! this works great! I had to play with it a little but this is superb! Thanks, I need to thank you very clear! (4:30 am)

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle it with Jquery:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){ 

//This is your button
$('#altern-panel-hided').toggle( 

    /* 
        first click.
        Function that show a hided panel
        and change the button text.
    */
    function(e){ 
        $('#panel-hided').slideDown();
        $(this).text('hide the panel');
        e.preventDefault();
    }, 

    /* 
        Secund click.
        Function that hide the panel
        and rechange the button text.
    */
    function(e){ 
        $('#panel-oculto').slideUp();
        $(this).text('Show panel');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

);
```

I hope it help you

Comment: This won't work with the OP's html structure: the missing div that they want to restore is a child of the element whose text is set, and it gets overwritten.

Comment: I suggest not to override, just hide that div